# Hide element if webcam is not detected (jhuckaby WebcamJS)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jhuckyaby WebcamJS. If there is no detected webcam show the id `#forHide`, else show the id `#upload`:

```
<div class="row" id="forHide">
    <div class="d-inline-block ml-3">
        <div id="my_camera" class="mb-2"></div>
            <input type=button value="Configure"      class="btn btn-primary btn-sm ml-1" onClick="configure()">
            <input type=button value="Take Snapshot"  class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onClick="take_snapshot()">
            <input type=button value="Save Snapshot"  class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onClick="saveSnap()">
    </div>

    <div class="d-inline-block ml-5">
        <div id="results"></div>
     </div>
</div>

<div id="upload">
    <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Select image to upload:
        <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

I read the docs on [GitHub](https://github.com/jhuckaby/webcamjs/blob/master/DOCS.md) and I tried to implement this code but somehow no result.

```
 Webcam.on( 'error', function(err) {
            // hide element
        } );
```

Answer (score 0):

Check below code to hide `forHide` id using pure JavaScript:

```
Webcam.on('error', function(err) {
  var x = document.getElementById("forHide");
  x.style.display = "none";
});
```

For more information read this : https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_hide_show.asp

Comment: still not working sir this is the whole code that i used https://imgur.com/a/v211xpM

Comment: `still not working` elaborate it more. What are you getting in `console.log(err);`
in this `error` event?

Comment: This means you are entering in `Webcam.on('error', function(err) { console.log(err) });`

Comment: the webcam.on('error, function(err){}) doesnt override the alert dialog as said in https://github.com/jhuckaby/webcamjs/issues/140